# how to use pip to install package to customized directory but respect dependencies

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I want to use pip3 to install python package to /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages. For example, I want to install xgboost, so I try

```
sudo -H pip3 install -t /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages xgboost
```

The problem is such command also install dependencies numpy and scipy even though they already exist in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, and when I use

```
sudo pip3 uninstall xgboost
```

it complain xgboost is not installed.

What I want:

1. pip3 just install dependencies when they are not exist in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
2. pip3 uninstall xgboost can work

Any help? Thanks

Comment: This sounds quite dangerous as it would be easy to mess up python installtions in this way. Maybe you could elaborate why you would want to do this?

Comment: I want to do this on my linux mint computer. Most of the time, I use apt-get to install most of the python packages, however, some of the python packages are not exist in the ubuntu/debian repository, so I have to use pip3 to install. Since linux mint update evey two years, I have to purge and reinstall the system. I want to write down the installation procedure in a python script. So I can use the python script every time and not to do the procedure manually.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to use `apt-get` for your python packages as the default choice? It sounds like you are making it overly complicated for yourself. If you would use `pip` or `conda` you could just write `requirements.txt` files or create virtual environments that you could make reproducible with a `yml` file